# Is it possible to have Test in vue single file component instead of seperate file?

Tags: vue.js

Has someone done this or tried this? production build should ofcourse filter out all the tests.
Would be great if it is possible.

```
<template>
 <p>{{ greeting }} World!</p>
</template>

<script>
 module.exports = {
  data: function () {
   return {
   greeting: 'Hello'
  }
 }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>

<test>
 import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
</test>
```

Comment: Yes, here is a project implementing this: https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-test-loader It uses the custom block functionality: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/custom-blocks.html#example